# I want to increase the frequency of each element of an array with particular amount?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

This is sample array;

[image]

I want it increase the frequency of each element by constant (taking 4 here);

*[64,64,64,64, 45, 45, 45, 45, 56, 56, 56, 56, 67, 67, 67, 67, 78, 78, 78, 78, 12, 12, 12, 12, 112, 112, 112, 112, 232, 232, 232, 232]*

Can anyone help me with this? Please it should not be hardcoded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat) to achieve this:

```
>>> a.repeat(4)
array([ 64,  64,  64,  64,  45,  45,  45,  45,  56,  56,  56,  56,  67,
        67,  67,  67,  78,  78,  78,  78,  12,  12,  12,  12, 112, 112,
       112, 112, 232, 232, 232, 232])
```

Comment: Your solution is a significant improvement on mine.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what the expanded frequency will be at the time when you create the array, you can use a list comprehension to expand it first:

```
import numpy as np
a_prime = [64, 45, 56, 67, 78, 12, 112, 232]
a = np.array([x for x in a for i in range(4)])
```

If you need to change the amount to expand it by, you could wrap this in a function:

```
def expand_frequency(lst, n):
    return [x for x in lst for i in range(n)]

a = np.array(expand_frequency(a_prime, 4))
```

I'm not sure if this is quite what you are looking for, but it should serve as a starting point.